# Users posting their same question multiple times

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that there exist some users on SP.SE who feel a need to continuously post their same questions over and over again because they do not get "good enough" answers in their previous posts.

I have tried flagging and closing multiple questions that fit the above behavior but they do not get the message.

Is there anything we can do to help kill this habit, besides flagging every single post?

Answer (score 3):

Flagging is a good start since that will gain moderators attention. If you feel the need to clarify to the users why you are flagging their posts, try to start a chatting session with the user. Argue for your standing point, but please be humble about other users having different standing points than you.

But, use the flagging of posts to get our attention, and if we find the need to take actions to clarify anything we will :)